# SET Table name in join query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to set table name in the following query:-

```
    SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
    from t1 
    inner join t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id
```

Assume the following schema for t1 and t2 table:-

```
   t1:-> id, field1, field2
   t2:-> id, field1, field2
```

I want something like:-

```
 t1_id, t1_field1, t1_field2, t2_id, t2_field1, t2_field2
```

Comment: You can use column name `Alias` while selection column

Comment: Alias is doable if no of columns in both table are few but I need it for more than 20 columns on each table.

Comment: Then you must needed something generic solution which create select query with all column name

Comment: You may use dynamic sql for generating column name with its corresponding alias name.

Answer (score 0):

SQL will not do this automatically for you.
You may use dynamic sql to first create your query using your column names for each table. Later on use that query to get your result.

```
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
 TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME' into @colname;
 SET @table = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
 SET @table_alias = 'T1';
 SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ',@table_alias,'.',@colname,' AS ',@table_alias,'_',@colname,' FROM ', @table);

 PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
 EXECUTE stmt;
```

This is not exact solution for your query but variant of this may help you to make your desired query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic query "This query should be your SELECT statement with all join conditions and where clause and so on..."

finally execute it to get the result....Below is a sample code for your question..

Declare @tblcols table ( ColPos int identity(1,1), queryColumn nvarchar(1000))

insert into @tblcols (  queryColumn)
SELECT (CONCAT(' ', table_name,'.', column_name, ' as ''', table_name, '__', column_name, ''' ')) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name in( 'Table1','Table2');

Declare @columnname nVarchar(MAX),@Join nVarchar(MAX);

Select @columnname = COALESCE(@columnname + ', ' + queryColumn, queryColumn) From @tblcols ;

Select @Join = 'FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.ID'

select @columnname = 'SELECT '+@columnname+' '+@Join

--select @columnname

EXEC(@columnname)